# How do I improve this question?

Tags: support, asking-questions, post-ban

How do I improve this question do get out of a question ban?

[How do i fadeIn a grid of images on scroll in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25320577/how-do-i-fadein-a-grid-of-images-as-they-come-in-to-view-scroll-with-jquery)

Comment: @psubsee2003 my question is about those 3 questions not the system

Comment: @psubsee2003 This includes posts from:

    users who can't be bothered to form sentences
    users who don't do the most basic kinds of research themselves
    users who barely even explain what it is they are trying to do Does not apply to me.......

Comment: `Can they just be erased from my account?` **is** a question about the system.  The System is a bit more tolerant than that - if those were the problem you would not have been able to ask those other 6 since then.  Any deleted, downvoted questions would count though.

Comment: @Plutonix ok well im in a real catch 22 then, because none of the downvoters will ever come back.

Comment: @Timothy you are asking about the system ("how do i make amends?" and "Can they just be erased from my account?").  If you asked "How do I improve this question"  and picked 1 of the questions, then that wouldn't be a duplicate.

Comment: @psubsee2003 XD i should have done that....

Comment: Do you have deleted questions recently which were DVed?

Comment: @Plutonix no why?

Comment: @Timothy and incidentally, it is never about 1 or 2 or 3 questions.  It is about all of your contributions.  The key is improving everything.  You have 9 other questions, none with a positive score.  You might have more luck working on those.

Comment: Any question you enhance so it gets a few upvotes is a good step, but it's easy to forget the deleted once even though they still count (and you can ask to get them undeleted after making them worthwhile). It does not matter who casts those up-votes you need, those who earlier judged your contributions bad or anyone else. (Though don't beg for upvotes, it won't work. At least before you really did your part and also gave it some time.)

Comment: Because deleted questions count towards bans.  Is the ban recent or since Sept 1 when you got 2 DVs?  I suspect there is something we cant see - it should take more than 3 older questions.

Comment: @Deduplicator Thanks. any tips on changing them?

Comment: @Plutonix yes the account has been banned for ages, i only remember deleting one question

Comment: it says none under deleted questions?

Comment: Just looked over your questions, and they seem a bit sparse on explanation (Some also seem to be scarcely researched). Keep in mind though that I seldom frequent those tags. You only have "recent deleted questions", which lists the last 30 or 60 days, not sure, as you ain't a mod.

Comment: @Deduplicator Ok i will look over all my questions and see what i can change. i think if i can just get one upvote for each question i will be out of the ban :).

Comment: Some of the question where done in a hurry when i needed to finish a site...

Comment: `"Some of the question where done in a hurry when i needed to finish a site..."` -- Remember that you're asking volunteers for help. You can't expect us to put in effort or appreciate it if you're in too much of a hurry to do so yourself. Please keep that in mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to be clear, your account isn't blocked for 3 bad questions. It's blocked for *three months* of questions, 16 in total, out of which only 4 have a score *greater than* 0. In total, 7 currently score less than 0, 4 are deleted, and 4 are sitting at 0. Going by past history, any question you ask stands a better chance of being downvoted than it does of being upvoted - so the system ain't betting on you anymore.

That out of the way, here are some things you could do to improve [the question you linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25320577/how-do-i-fadein-a-grid-of-images-on-scroll-with-a-delay-in-jquery):

1. **Describe what you've tried.** It's great that you posted your attempt at a solution - but chances are, at least some of the folks who might be willing to answer your question are gonna read it only with reluctance, as a way to ward off the possibility that what you're asking for help with and what you're actually trying to do are somewhat or even completely different. Spend maybe two sentences describing your thought process, laying out the details of what you're trying to accomplish, your goals, expectations, et cetera.
2. **Describe what isn't working.** Again, awesome that you posted what you've done so far, even better that you included a runnable jsfiddle example (btw, have you heard about [snippets?](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)) - but you don't mention what's wrong with it. Am I gonna run the fiddle and see immediately what you're talking about? Or is this gonna turn into a huge bug-hunt where if I don't scroll at just the right speed everything appears to work? Or nothing works, ever? Or I get rickrolled? Imagine you got a bug report from one of your users that consisted of nothing but the text "I tried something how do I do it?" - would you send them a t-shirt?
3. **Fix your capitalization.** I know, I know, this probably seems petty - and honestly, lower-casing i doesn't bother me all that much. But spelling jQuery as "Jquery" is positively infuriating. I mean it. I'm all angried up now. I blame you for my cornbread not coming out of the pan cleanly. It's because you didn't spell jQuery right. Rawr.

All that said, this isn't even close to the most problematic question on your account. Let's look at the *last* question you asked: [Directional transition mouse-event area seems to be offset in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25437409/jquery-directional-transitions-not-working-properly-in-chrome)

- You mis-capitalize jQuery *again*.
- You still don't state clearly what problem you're trying to solve - and worse, your title is effectively worthless - stripped of the information available in the question *tags*, it boils down to "something isn't working".
- I'm pretty sure it's more or less a duplicate of the question we discussed above.

#### Solutions

So, what should you do about all this? Well, you have two options, depending on whether or not you're asking a "How do I..." question (the first one discussed) or a "What's wrong with what I'm doing?" question (the last one discussed).

- **How do I?** questions should be *explicit*. Don't gloss over anything - presumably you have a *very* specific need, so don't assume anyone else knows what the details are! It's great if you provide details on what you've already tried, but there again - be specific on *why* you tried that, and *where* it didn't work out for you. This gives anyone answering a head start on explaining where you went wrong - they don't have to reverse-engineer your attempt to figure out what you already know!
- **What did I do wrong?** questions are just the other side of the coin from "How do I" questions - you *still* want to explain exactly what you're trying to do, but now you *must* explain exactly what you've tried, why you tried it, and where that's failed. Realistically, a good debugging question is no different from a good HOWTO question - that the majority of debugging questions don't include such details and still get answered is little more than a testament to how tolerant and helpful folks on SO are. See also: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: That's really clear. I get what you mean  "works half the time". I never really thought much about capitalization. Yes i have used snippet... i should use them more. So have you got any tips on what i should change??

Comment: See my last edit.

Comment: So basically be super detailed and tell them what i have tried in great detail. and always use code snippets and upload it to JS fiddle or Code pen or alike.

Comment: so once i change my question how does it get upvoted. the people who downvoted them are long gone???

Comment: Others may find it and up-vote it, @Timothy. Each edit bumps the question to the front page for a brief moment, so if it catches their eye they may decide to read and vote... Also, don't forget aps.

Comment: APS? what is that?

Comment: APS == "I got distracted and palm-mashed my keyboard half-way through that comment". Pretty sure I meant to say, "Don't forget that well-written questions will tend to attract fewer *downvotes* over time as well, meaning you aren't getting in any deeper".

Comment: Thanks, when i get the time i will go through and rewrite all my questions.